# How to copy field data from object to object with a button-click via Apex?

Tags: apex, related-list

I want to copy field data from one object to another with a click on a button.
I want to get a snapshot of the current family status and copy the data from related `son` and `father` data.

I have an custom object `son` with the following fields:
`s_name`, `s_street` and `father`, where `father` is a lookup to object `father`, which has the fields `f_name` and `f_age`.

I want to have a button on the `son` page, saying `new family`, which populates another custom object `family` with the respective fields from the originating objects: `s_name`, `s_street` etc.

How would I realize such a copy action via `Apex`?

Comment: You'll likely need to write some Apex code backing the button to handle this action, as it isn't out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

If you want on a button call go for custom button with apex behind it doing job of creation and populating the data.

If you want that as soon as a new Son record and automatic family record is created and populated go for trigger,

//apex method pseudo code

```
public pagerefrence createfamilyrecord(){

 Id recordId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('Id');

 List<Son__c> lstson=[Select Id ,s_name, s_street from Son__c where id =:recordId];

 if(lstson__c.size()>0){

   Family__c fam=new Family__c();

   fam.field1=lstson.get(0).s_name;

    fam.field2=lstson.get(0).s_street;

    insert faml;

    return null;//Return where you want the navigation to be 
    }

   }
```

//Visualforce pseudo code

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!createfamilyrecord}" value="NEw Family" id="theButton"/>
```

Comment: It's supposed to be on a button click, not on a new `son` record. Do you have any link on the Apex code?

Comment: I got the question more concise, and sorry, your answer does not solve the problem yet.

Comment: updated the answer!Hope that helps you